# Firebase - Query by nested key

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a data structure like this:

```
UserOrders
    unique-userid-100
        unique-orderid-456
            [order details here] 
        unique-orderid-123
            [order details here]
    unique-userid-200
        unique-orderid-789
            [order details here]
    ....
```

For admin functionalities, I need to query using the orderid (without knowing the userid) and get order details? How can I efficiently do this?

I tried this but I get all the data under UserOrders.

```
ref.child("UserOrders").queryOrdered(byChild: "unique-orderid-456").observeSingleEvent(...
```

Comment: Which data are you trying to get specifically? A single order?

Comment: Yes, I want to get the order details for an order id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Firebase API, we can only filter one level nested data.

So, for this first it will be needed to map users to there orders like :-

UserOrders

```
unique-userid-100

    unique-orderid-456 = true
    unique-orderid-123 = true
unique-userid-200
    unique-orderid-789 = true
....
```

Then find userid for an order using query :-

```
let ref  = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        ref.child("UserOrders").queryOrdered(byChild: "unique-orderid-456").queryEqual(toValue: true).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
  // here userid will be obtained for an order, using this ref/<userid>/unique-orderid-456 can be observed to get order details

})
```

This is a work around, but it will be good if you can reconsider to restructure data

Please refer similar:- [Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested)

Comment: The referenced post says "deep queries are now a feature" in Firebase

Comment: deep queries can be done when path is known, as in this post: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html , without known userid, i believe it is not possible.